# How to configure atlantis or bitbucket to interpetate terraform plans?

Tags: terraform, bitbucket, terragrunt, atlantis

Is there anything I can configure in Atlantis or Bitbucket in order to have a clean plan? At the moment I can see this in the Bitbucket comments:

[image]

All I have done so far is:

1. `terragrunt plan -no-color`
2. - env:
     # Reduce Terraform suggestion output
     name: TF_IN_AUTOMATION
     value: 'true'

Is anything else I can do?

Comment: The codes you've highlighted are terminal control codes, and so the `-no-color` option should have disabled them. However, the output you shared here is from `terraform init` rather than `terraform plan`, so I think you'll need to run `terraform init -no-color` too, or you can set the environment variable `TF_CLI_ARGS=-no-color` to add that option to all Terraform commands you run.

Comment: To hide that _entire warning_ (rather than just the control codes used to color it) you should check the `.terraform.lock.hcl` file into your version control system and configure your automation to run `terraform init -lockfile=readonly`; your lock file should be populated by your developers in their development environments, not dynamically in your automation system.

Comment: Thanks @MartinAtkins using `TF_CLI_ARGS=-no-color` solved my issue! Regarding the add `.terraform.lock.hcl` to version control, I'll definitely look into it